# Downloading a zip file returns a corrupt zip using servlets

Tags: java, servlets, zip, download

I am trying to create a zip file using servlets but it returns me a corrupt zip file , here is the code for that in zipcontents function i am creating the zip , can someone help me out. Thanks in Advance.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,
    IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    res.setContentType("application/zip");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.zip;");

    fsep = File.separator;
    rootDir = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("Projects" + File.separator + "amrurta"));
    File list[] = rootDir.listFiles();
    zos = new ZipOutputStream(bout);
    zipContents(list, rootDir.getName() + fsep);
    zos.close();
    res.getWriter().println(bout.toString());
}

public void zipContents(File[] file, String dir) {
    // dir - directory in the zip file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) { // zip files
            if (file[i].isFile()) {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file[i]);
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(dir + file[i].getName()));
                // shows how its stored
                // System.out.println(dir+file[i].getName());
                int bytes_read;
                while ((bytes_read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);

                fis.close();
            }
        } // for

        // create empty dir if theres no files inside
        if (file.length == 1)
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(dir + fsep)); // this part is erroneous i think

        for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) { // zip directories
            if (file[i].isDirectory()) {
                File subList[] = file[i].listFiles();

                // for dir of varying depth
                File unparsedDir = file[i];
                String parsedDir = fsep + file[i].getName() + fsep; // last folder
                while (!unparsedDir.getParentFile().getName().equals(rootDir.getName())) {
                    unparsedDir = file[i].getParentFile();
                    parsedDir = fsep + unparsedDir.getName() + parsedDir;
                }
                parsedDir = rootDir.getName() + parsedDir; // add input_output as root

                zipContents(subList, parsedDir);
            }
        } // for

    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are too much problems in the code. the major ones which springs in are:

1. The `zos` is been declared as servlet instance variable. This is *not threadsafe*. It is been shared among multiple requests. You risk that a subseuent request overwrites the previous one when it's not been finished.
2. The binary ZIP content is been converted to character data with `bout.toString()`. This will definitely corrupt binary data. You should write binary data as binary data using the usual `InputStream#read()`/`OutputStream#write()` loop.
3. The code does not call `zos.closeEntry()` at end of each entry.

I think #2 is the major cause. You don't need `ByteArrayOutputStream`. It's only an unnecessary memory hog. Just wrap the `response.getOutputStream()` in `ZipOutputStream`.

```
ZipOutputStream output = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
zipFiles(directory.listFiles(), output);
output.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possible reason is different JVM versions of application server and compiler which compiles servlet.
Very rare issue but veeery hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could create like this
`ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(res. getOutputStream());`
And every zip entry you write into zip entry will be streamed back to the caller.